# Python3.10 script error

Tags: 20.04, python

Ubuntu 20.04, Python3.10.
I execute small script and receive an error:

```
STDERR message(s) from external script: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/revoscalepy/__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
    from .RxSerializable import RxMissingValues
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/revoscalepy/RxSerializable.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/usr/bin/python3.10"
STDERR message(s) from external script: 
  * The NumPy version is: "1.24.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
```

How can I fix it?
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Comment: Yes, but there are common advices, I have made them. And error still exists even when I do 1 statement: #import pandas

Comment: That URL has a section "*If none of the following tips help you, please be sure to note the following:*" and a list of five items. Only two are shown in your question. Please edit your question to add the remaining three. Please do not comment on your own question. Instead, edit your question in response to comments. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable (not for conversation).